# Extract elements of certain type from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have a multidimensional array I obtained from an Excel file (raw data from cells stripped of any formatting, styling info,etc.). Example of array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      string(5) "aaaaa"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      float(666)
    }
  }
}
```

String-type cells represent ordinary text entered into a worksheet cells, while float-type cells represent numbers entered there.

Is there any method to extract the 'strings' and 'floats' from such an array? Or, can one at least delete all/filter out other info from an array by the type of its elements, leaving only 'string' and 'float' elements there?

Thank you!

Comment: You can always foreach through the whole thing with `is_string()`, `is_float()`, etc.

Comment: You can use array_filter together with Loek suggestions. Link of doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the array items recursively and remove the items which is not string, float or array with data.

Code example:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        ['A' => 'aaaaa'],
        ['A' => null],
        ['A' => null],
        ['A' => (float)666]
    ]
];

function filterData($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value))
            $value = filterData($value);

        if ($value === [] || (!is_array($value) && !is_string($value) && !is_float($value)))
            unset($array[$key]);
    }

    return $array;
}
var_dump(filterData($data));

/* result
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      string(5) "aaaaa"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      float(666)
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might use a combination of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and in the callback of array_filter check if the value is either a float or a string:

```
$arrays = [
    [
        ['A' => 'aaaaa'],
        ['A' => null],
        ['A' => null],
        ['A' => (float)666]
    ]
];

$arrays = array_map(function($x) {
    return array_filter($x, function($y) {
        return is_float($y['A']) || is_string($y['A']);
    });
}, $arrays);

var_dump($arrays);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7tg81)

That would result in:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      string(5) "aaaaa"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["A"]=>
      float(666)
    }
  }
}
```